# If I put on a shirt then put on a coat, am I wearing two-tiered clothes?

Tags: phrase-request

What are possible ways to describe my action of putting on two clothes, and what are possible ways to describe my situation after putting on two clothes one on top of the other? What ways of describing can generalize, so that a phrase or sentence can apply when the number of clothes would become three? Or even One?

How to say that if I put on two upper wears and two trousers, so I am wearing uniformly two-tiered clothes, instead of wearing four clothes?

Answer (score 1):

**Layer** is common way of expressing this is in English ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/layer))

If you put on a shirt and then put on a coat you are wearing two layers of clothing. If you add an overcoat, you have three layers. If you are only wearing the shirt, you are wearing a single layer.